# How to synchronously download data in WinRT?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-runtime

I am migrating app for WinRT. In the old app there is used `WebClient`. By this `WebClient` it downloads data a then bind them to ui. In the new app I want to do the same. But only way I found is to use `HttpClient`, which has to be awaited. That means I let download the file and before download is complete, program tries to bind data and program crashes. Is there option, how to download stream/file synchronously? I tought awaited operation acts like sync operation and program/thread will "pause" until it completion, but obviously not.

Comment: Could you show the code that is trying to bind the data? This should be done after you have awaited for the download to complete.

Comment: You can bind at any time, just need to notify binding to update.

Answer (score 1):

You can use model for data that implements INotifyPropertyChanged

```
    private List<string> _myList;
    public List<string> MyList
    {
        get { return _myList; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _myList)) return;
            _myList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

And when you download data with async you would need to do it this way:

```
    var result = await ...//download and parse data
    MyList = result.Items;
```

In XAML you need to bind to MyList.
This would trigger binding to update.

INotifyPropertyChanged implementation looks like this:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```